# How to give the maximum range in regular expression for entering the numbers?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, regex

hi want to restrict the user so that the user cannot enter the phone number more than the limit.
here is my regular expression `^[+0-9]+$`
this matches exactly +923319650897 but it also enable the user to enter unlimited numbers.

How can i restrict the user for entering numbers more than  the limit, while making some changes in the above regular expression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that a regex such as this:

```
^\+?[0-9]{n,m}$
```

would suit better, where `n` is the minimum number of allowed digits and `m` is the maximum number of allowed digits.

Putting the `+` within the brackets will also allow multiple `+` being inserted in the phone number, hence why I put it outside, and the `?` to mean that it might not be present as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the regular expression, like this,

```
^[+0-9]{13}$
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this

> ^[+0-9]+${13}

here 13 is number of Maximum range

Comment: Your regex simply won't even "compile", you cannot do `${13}` would be `[0-9]{13}`

Comment: I just add {13} in your statement to just let you know how to give maximum range

Comment: I'm not the one who asked for the regex I'm just correcting all your answers